# How to remove first key from json

Tags: javascript, json

I need to remove first index in json

json:

```
{"data":[{"label":"Data","data":1},{"label":"Website","data":1}]}
```

I need:

```
 [{"label":"Data","data":1},{"label":"Website","data":1}]
```

- if I try to delete.data then it outputs `object{}`

JS code:

```
function drawChart() {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function (json) {
        // callback function which gets called when your request completes. 
        var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
        console.log(myJsonString);
        Morris.Donut({
            element: 'donut-example',
            data: myJsonString // use returned data to plot the graph
        });
    });
}
```

Can anybody tell me where I have done wrong? Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Just refer `json.data` as it hold the `array`, do not `stringify` it..

Comment: @Turnip, `myJsonString` holds a `string`, not `object`

Comment: Just use `data: json.data`, no need to `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {"data":[{"label":"Data","data":1},{"label":"Website","data":1}]};

data = data.data
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: ya i have fixed i was JSON.stringify i removed it and it worked

Comment: can you tell how could i rename string :  [{"label":"Data","data":1},{"label":"Website","data":1}] to  [{"label":"Data","value":1},{"label":"Website","value":1}]

Comment: @afeef var arr =  [{"label":"Data","data":1},{"label":"Website","data":1}];

arr.map(function(element, index) {

 var temp = element.label;
  element.label = element.data;
  element.data = temp;
  arr[index] = element;
});   There might definitely be a simpler solution, but its just not in my head ;)